# Image orientation lost when resizing with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, orientation

I need to show an image in the largest size possible so I use javascript to create a square div with the maximum dimensions that fit the browser window.

I load the image and then I then change the width and height attributes to values that will make the image fit.

This works fine for 99% of images, but I have some that are shown in landscape format when they actually in portrait. I know they should be portrait because they are shown correctly in Windows explorer, Photoshop etc, and even when I right-click on the displayed image in a browser and select "show image in new window"

I have even rotated the image with PhotoShop and it is still shown landscape.

This makes me think that metadata is not being respected.

In ASPX Page_Load... imgImage.ImageUrl = "~/" & tPath

In HTML

```
function resizeImg() {
        var windowWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var windowHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        var imgMax = windowHeight - 54;
        var div = document.getElementById('divImage');
        div.style.width = imgMax  + 'px';
        div.style.height = imgMax + 'px';
        var divW = div.offsetWidth;
        var divH = div.offsetHeight;
        var winR = divW/divH
        var newImgH = imgH;
        var newImgW = imgW;
        if(newImgW > divW) {
            newImgW=divW
            newImgH = Math.floor(Math.round(divW / imgR));
        }   
        if(newImgH > divH) {
            newImgH=divH
            newImgW =Math.floor(Math.round(divH * imgR));
        }   
        img.setAttribute('width',newImgW);
        img.setAttribute('height',newImgH);
        img.setAttribute('hspace',(divW - newImgW)/2);
        img.setAttribute('vspace', (divH - newImgH) / 2);
```

}

Comment: *but I have some that are shown in landscape format when they actually in portrait* <-- Do you mean that the dimensions are altered such that the image is wider than it is tall and the image is resized to fit those dimensions? Because it's impossible for any code or software to alter an image from portrait to landscape or vice versa - - the way it was taken is the way it was taken.

Comment: It's usually done with the "orientation" flag in the Exif data but I think jpegs may have another flag in the jpeg metadata.